# The set of bounded continuous functions is a closed subspace of that of bounded functions

Tags: functional-analysis

suppose S is a metric space and $B(S)$ is the set of bounded functions and $C_b(S)$ is the set consisting of bounded continuous functions.

Prove that $C_b(S)$ is a closed subspace of $B(S)$.

I thought of looking at the complement $B(S) \backslash C_b(S) = \{f| \text{ f is bounded and not continuous}\}$ and proving this is open.

But how does one check that for each element $f \in  B(S) \backslash C_b(S)$, there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $B_f(\epsilon) \subset B(S) \backslash C_b(S)$?

Comment: Use metrics here! Then take a sequence in $C_b(S)$ that converges in $B(S)$ with respect to the metric of $B(S)$ (figure out which one!). What can you say about the limit? What properties does $C_b(S)$ have?

Comment: @noctusraid Suppose we take the supremum norm, then we can see that $C_b(S)$ converges in $B(S)$ to a limit that is again in $C_b(S)$. How can one conclude that this is closed....

What definition of open/closed are you using?

Comment: The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm on the function space is given by the sup norm $\|f\|:=\sup\{|f(x)|x\in S\}$. Convergence of functions in sup-norm is called uniform convergence. It is a general statement that a uniform limit of continuous functions is again continuous.

To see that let $x_n \to x$, let $f_m \in C_b(S)$ and $f_m \to f \in C(s)$. Consider $\epsilon>0$.

Since $f_m \to f$ there exists an $M$ st for $m>M$, $\|f_m-f\|<\epsilon$. Now let $m>M$, since $f_m$ is continuous and $x_n\to x$ we have an $N$ so that $|f_m(x_n)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$. So for a given $\epsilon$, choose $m, N$ as above and if $n>N$:

$$|f(x_n)-f(x)|≤|f(x_n)-f_m(x_n)|+|f_m(x_n)-f_m(x)|+|f_m(x)-f(x)|≤2\|f-f_m\|+\epsilon≤3\epsilon$$

Which shows $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer (based more on OP's knowledge):

In a metric space $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_X)$ and $A \subset X$ we have the following assertion:

$$ x \in \bar{A} \iff \exists (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset A: x_n\to x \in X $$

This means in words: an element $x$ of a subspace $A \subset X$ is in the closure of $A$ (the smalles closed set containing $A$) if and only if there is a sequence **in A** that **converges in X**. To see that this is equivalent to the definition of closed I leave for you to check with 2 hints:

First: Use the toplogical definition of a closure.
Second: How does a topology induces by a metric look like? How is convergence defined?

Now with this at hands we pick an arbitrary sequence $f_n$ in $C_b(S)$ which **does convergence in $B(S)$ !** If the limit, say $f$, now lies in $C_b(S)$ we have shown that $C_b(S)=cl(C_b(S))$. To conclude see post above.

Comment: saw this definition thanks!